# SQL Server : result of "counting" subquery is not numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following in a stored procedure

```
DECLARE @AssocCount INT;

SET @AssocCount = (SELECT COUNT(Associations.GroupId) AS 'count'
                   FROM Personnel.Persons Persons
                   INNER JOIN Personnel.Associations Associations
                              ON Persons.PersonId = Associations.PersonId
                              AND Associations.GroupId = @GroupID
                              AND GETDATE() BETWEEN Associations.StartDate 
                              AND ISNULL(Associations.EndDate, GETDATE())
                   GROUP BY Associations.PersonId);
```

All my tests looked like every execution would return either `0` or `1` or possibly `>1` under some rare, odd cases. In production though we hit a case in which the subquery found no records to count at all. The result does not appear to be `null`. I tried the following without success:

```
SET @AssocCount = ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(Associations.GroupId) AS 'count'
                          FROM Personnel.Persons Persons
                          INNER JOIN Personnel.Associations Associations
                                     ON Persons.PersonId = Associations.PersonId
                                     AND Associations.GroupId = @GroupID
                                     AND GETDATE() BETWEEN Associations.StartDate AND ISNULL(Associations.EndDate, GETDATE())
                          GROUP BY Associations.PersonId), 0);
```

How can I check the subquery for an empty result and coerce a zero value?

Comment: @squillman _COUNT() will always return a value_ Normally true, but not true for a case where you're counting one column and grouping by another, or counting one column but searching with `WHERE` conditions on another column and a group by.

Comment: @ZLK Ah, right.  Thanks for that.  Deleted my comment.

Comment: That's just it, that count is not returning a value.  In this case the "person" in question has no group associations and the result of the query run by hand is empty

Comment: The isnull should work, though. Because @AssocCount default value is null. If no result set is returned, it will still be null... So using isnull/coalesce would work. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Actually, in the first case I am getting this error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`  Sorry, should have reported that earlier.   Using the ISNULL skips me past the error but the result is empty and not zero

Comment: Are you sure it's _this_ subquery that returns more than one value?

Comment: Ok, yes that's different.  You're getting multiple records back from the subquery because you're counting one column and grouping by another.  Can you update your question with the schemas for your two tables and what you're trying to get form the subquery?

Comment: thanks ZLK setting a default value worked like a charm

Comment: This will continue to (depending on data) because of your `GROUP BY`. If you have two `Associations.PersonId` then you'll get two rows and your query will fail. What is the purpose of the group by?

Comment: Nick, that is a good question... I was editing a legacy stored proc but thinking about this again, I don't need a count of how many time a person is a member of the same group.  I just need to know if they are in this one specific group! I can rewrite this as a simpler test for group membership. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @AssocCount INT = 0;

SELECT  @AssocCount =  COUNT(Associations.GroupId) 
               FROM Personnel.Persons Persons
               INNER JOIN Personnel.Associations Associations
                          ON Persons.PersonId = Associations.PersonId
                          AND Associations.GroupId = @GroupID
                          AND GETDATE() BETWEEN Associations.StartDate 
                          AND ISNULL(Associations.EndDate, GETDATE())
               GROUP BY Associations.PersonId
```